Error: Expected a python object, received a character
I am trying to load a h5ad file to R:
ref_anndata <- anndata::read_h5ad("/Fetal_nephron.h5ad")

where the object seems to load correctly:
ref_anndata

#> AnnData object with n_obs × n_vars = 10790 × 33694
#> obs: 'Barcode', 'Short_Sample', 'Experiment', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Stage', 'Selection', 'celltype', #> 'compartment'
#>   var: 'ID'
#>   obsm: 'X_umap

However, when I tried to access ref_anndata$obs, I get:
Error: Expected a python object, received a character
Can anyone help with this? Thank you.

Did the installation and example from https://cannoodt.dev/2021/02/anndata-for-r/ work as expected?

This issue was fixed by rstudio/reticulate#1591, so it should be fixed with the next release of reticulate.
